# What to do if the render does not work correctly

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

[image]

I think the photo shows what's wrong.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Also verbally explain what the issue is, don't just post an image. It may not be immediately clear what you are talking about, and the question can't be found by searching, making it useless to visitors with similar issues that may be looking for an answer

Answer (score 2):

A guess... this cube is rendered but hidden in viewport:

[image]

If not this one, most likely something around that (something hidden in viewport but rendered).